# Where can I find a minute timer watch with rotating face?

Tags: alarm-clock

To improve my productivity, I’ve been looking for a watch with a minute timer to force myself to complete tasks on time (e.g. 15,30,45…min). Requirements:

- **Timer should be set via a rotating face**: fastest to set (like kitchen minute timers)

[image]

- **Watch must be analog**: smartwatches provide too much distraction and need to be recharged constantly.
- **Timer should have vibrating sound**: because beeping will be too annoying to me and colleagues on the long run.

Ideally the watch should have casual design.

I've been searching online and asked in several watch stores, no luck finding this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because analog watches do not fall within our scope ("requested device must be a digital platform capable of performing more than one meaningful task, or must require a connection to such a platform to function").